# KQL ipv4_is_in_range with datatable

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Good day,

Attempting to check IPAddress from SiginLogs with a datatable. I am able to perform the Scalar function  ipv4_is_in_range() with a single value. *Ips are changed for privacy*

ex:
`ipv4_is_in_range(IPAddress, '127.0.0.255/24')`

When I try to use a declared datatable it does not recognize the values and returns nothing.

ex:

```
let srcIPs = datatable (checkIP:string) ['127.0.0.1/24'];
SigninLogs
| union  srcIPs
| where ipv4_is_in_range( IPAddress, checkIP)
```

or

```
let srcIPs = datatable (checkIP:string) [
'127.0.0.1/24',
'8.8.8.8',
'1.1.1.1/16'
];
SigninLogs
| union  srcIPs
| where ipv4_is_in_range( IPAddress, checkIP)
```

if I replace the 'where' with 'extend' I will get one IP address that does show correctly but will include another IP address that is not within that range.

My question is how do I get the function to recognize the values from srcIPs correctly?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin

Comment: Also see this plural version of the function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-is-in-any-range-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael. I went a head a revisited that document and reattempted. The workspace still shows and error when I hover ipv4_lookup stating it is not defined. YET. It still ran, something I didn't attempt. Now the code looks like.

```
let IP_Data = datatable(network:string)
[
"127.0.0.1",
"8.8.8.8/24",
"192.168.0.1",
"10.0.240.255/21"
];
SigninLogs
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(IP_Data, IPAddress, network)
| where UserType == "Member"
| project-reorder IPAddress, UserPrincipalName
```

So this code got me what I was looking for. TY all for your assistance.

Answering my own question with working code for record.